# How to directly add a key-value pair to a dictionary with "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type" error?

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3

I have a dictionary that contains a JSON object. I'm trying to directly manipulate that dictionary to add a key-value pair. However, I am getting the **Cannot assign to immutable expression of type** Any error.

I know that the value of `Any` is immutable, it cannot be changed. I managed to obtain a reference to it to store it in a different dictionary and applied a key-value pair there, but I like to change the original dictionary to reduce code repetition.

Currently this is the output of the dictionary:

```
dict = ["Object": 
                [ ["number_1": -117.13,
                   "number_2": 32.91,
                   "link": http://www.google.com]
                ]
       ]
```

What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
( (dict["Object"] as! [Dictionary<String, Any>])[0] as! Dictionary<String, Any>)["image"] = UIImage(named: "")
```

I'm trying to add "image" as another key with a `UIImage` as the value, but I can't due to `Any` being an immutable type.

How can I **directly** manipulate `dict` to add a key-value pair?

FYI: `dict` is declared as a `var`, not `let`

Comment: Is `dict` declared with `var` or `let`?

Comment: @TomHarrington: updated